# How can I learn Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Can someone help me with Salesforce Marketing Cloud material to learn?

Where are some good resources for walkthroughs and tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce offers a fantastic, FREE online [**Trailhead**](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) to learn about all our products.

Answer (score 0):

Trailhead is good.

You can also go through this [**Marketing Cloud Getting Started Program**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220226&type=2)
or download the  [**Journey Builder Success Guide**](https://www.marketingcloud.com/journey-builder-success-guide/)